# Google Script Slow to Parse JDBC ResultSet

Tags: mysql, parsing, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm investigating an option to store data in MySQL, to reduce calls to GoogleFinance() which frequently shows errors through not loading etc - mainly when retrieving historical data.

However, I've been finding JDBC calls to be very slow. 3-8secs to establish a connection, 1 sec to executeQuery, **BUT** parsing the JDBCResultSet can take 30-190 secs, for just 2275 rows x 8 cols.

As a novice I'm using code I adapted from online examples, just wondering if it can be improved to reduce the time the Parsing takes? The parse section is:

```
// Parse ResultSet into Array
var numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();  // numCols = 8 
var rowCnt = 0;
var results = [];
while (rs.next()) {
  rowData = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
    rowData.push(rs.getString(i));
  }
  results.push(rowData);
  rowCnt++;
  if ((rowCnt % 100) == 0) {
    Logger.log('rowCnt: ' + rowCnt);
  }
}
var end = new Date();
var diff = (end - begin) / 1000;
var begin = new Date();
Logger.log('ResultSet Parsed ' + rowCnt + ' rows in ' + diff + 's');// 2275 rows in 37.2s, 187.8s, 16.8s, 160.4s, 33.8s
```

The timing of the parse operation shows wildly varying times, for the same ResultSet. Google Sheets is connecting to the latest version of MySQL on a home computer, via a 50Mmbs connection which I've checked via speedtest.net, so it doesn't seem like a connection issue.

Any suggestions to improve this lengthy operation would be welcome, otherwise I may have to ditch this option as impracticable.

Comment: You can use Yahoo Finance which imports a big json with lots of information into its web page. It could be an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, will have a look - do they offer an API?

Comment: Looks like the Yahoo API is available via Rakuten RapidAPI: https://blog.api.rakuten.net/api-tutorial-yahoo-finance/

Comment: No, but since you get the json, you can parse it like this : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wh6JzXG8YJiipDBsuF_kgsrgHHtMxT9Co_rDCYplOU8/copy

Comment: Thanks Mike! The examples will be a big help.

Comment: I'm not formally posting a response as I'm interested in the solution when using JDBC, maybe in the future I'll post something in GitHub for Yahoo.

Comment: I haven't found much online insofar as Google Sheets and JDBC goes. My impression - though that may be wrong - is that Google doesn't consider connecting Sheets to databases seriously.  
Even prepareStatement() does not work for the simplest of examples, always "timing out". There are other issues too.